# How do I implement a calendar under the corresponding section?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using swift and attempting to develop a school app. However, I'm a tad lost. I've made sections using the following code. How do I implement a calendar under the corresponding Calendar section? I've used UITableViewController to create my different sections. Posted below is the code.

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {


    let School = "School"
    let sections = [
        "News", "Calendar", "iMotivated"
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none

        navigationItem.title = "school's owls"
       navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: School)

    }

        override func tableView(_ tableVIew: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return 3
        }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: School, for: indexPath)

        let seeingSections = self.sections[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = seeingSections

        return cell
    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        window = UIWindow()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
        window?.rootViewController = navController
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about selecting a row in your section, then use the following method:

`table(_:didSelectRowAt:)`

## Suggestion:

- When posting a question, let it be as generic as possible, not all users would understand your context / app.
- Example: Calendar is something specific to your app, so specify it as a section instead.